# Git: for fork with multiple configured remotes, how to query for specific remote repo

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fork

I want to retrieve the remote repo configured for upstream for my local branch.

I can do `git remote -v`, which gives me origin and upstream repos. But I was wondering if there was **a way to query for a specific remote repo**, in this case, upstream.

```
$git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:origin/practice-repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:origin/practice-repo.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:remoterepo/practice-repo.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:remoterepo/practice-repo.git (push)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "query" ? You can push, fetch (and pull) to/from a specific remote by specifying it (e.g. `git fetch upstream`).

Comment: by query, I mean i'd like to get the name of the specific remote Im looking for. In this case, the upstream remote repo

Comment: To get the url from the name you can do `git remote get-url <name>`. In you case, `git remote get-url upstream`.

Comment: Do you have any criteria for *specific remote I'm looking for*?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the special ref `@{u}` :

```
# works in bash, for powershell: put quotes around '@{u}'
> git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u}   
origin/my/branch
```

The first part of this reference will indicate the remote.

---

One more systematic way to extract just the remote name of the remote tracking branch :

The link between one of your local branches and its remote counter part is stored in your repo's `.git/config` file :

```
> cat .git/config
...
[branch "my/branch"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/my/branch
...
```

You can access this information from the command line :

```
# get current branch's name :
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
# get config value :
git config --get branch.$branch.remote

# as a one liner :
git config --get branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).remote
```